# What did the night sky look like 100,000 years ago?

Tags: night-sky

Question in the title. Would any constellations be identifiable?

Comment: You can use an application like Stellarium to e.g. set the date to a future time and show what will happen constellations at some future date.  The outlines can be displayed and you'll see the effect of time.

Comment: @StephenG use of the Stellarium will tell you when to Wait For It and when the next Zanclean flood will happen

Answer (score 4):

(Here I assume by "constellation" you mean "pattern of stars", rather than "region of the sky". To be a pedant one should use "asterism" for a pattern of stars.)

Some asterisms will be recognisable, but there can be some significant proper motion over that period.

Some stars will move more than others. Generally, closer stars will appear to have moved further than more distant stars. So the stars that make up the asterism of "the plough" (which are fairly close) will have moved more, but will still be in the same general region of the sky. On the other hand the bright stars of Orion are more distant. In 100000 years ago the general appearance of Orion would already have formed.

Videos showing 
The past and future of the Plough https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txJH8RlIoXQ

The future of Orion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KFQD6Bpnm0

Comment: In the "pedant" vein: closer stars have in fact moved farther than distant stars,  in units of theta and phi   :-)